# How to delete starting rows of an Excel sheet (.xls format) in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The excel file (.xls) contains 20 invalid rows at the beginning that I would like to delete.

I tried to skip rows by `pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = "Sheet1", skiprows=range(1, 21)`, it didn't work.

It throws an assertion error  `assert _unused_i == nstrings - 1`

openpyxl throws: `openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.`

Manually deleting the top 20 rows and loading it with pandas work. I'm struggling to delete the top 20 rows programmatically.

Comment: I'm okay with either of the options. I want to skip when reading the excel file or delete the rows and read the excel file

Comment: Likely also need `engine='xlrd'` when using `pd.read_excel`. `skiprows` only needs an int.

Comment: Received the same error with engine='xlrd'

huge stack-trace and an error: assert _unused_i == nstrings - 1

Comment: Note that `skiprows` is zero-indexed.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. I tried with range(0, 21) and it still did not work.

Comment: `range(0, 21)` is the first 21 rows btw, not 20.

Comment: I tried with (0, 20), (0, 21), (1, 20), (1, 21) and it still didn't work :(

Can we delete the top 20 rows instead?